# Looking for a location based push service

Tags: android, push-notification, geolocation

I am looking for location based push service. What I want to achieve with it is to be able to send requests to some geo location areas like London for example.

I have been trying to use PushWoosh, but it seems that their maximum range of GeoLocation is 1000 meters, which is too small area, as I would want to be able to send push for whole city.

I know it is possible to just send json with custom data area defining area of message, however I am looking for out of the box solution that could do this work for me. Especially because one of the requirements is that some non technical people will be able to send geo located pushes to the users, so I would need some nice looking frontend for them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a wordpress plugin.. I think it may can solve your problem..

http://smartiolabs.com/product/push-notification-system/